# How to increase year range in Hijri DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, calendar

In my windows application, I have a `DateTimePicker` to insert a Hijri date into the database. But, the `DateTimePicker` doesn't allow dates of more than '29-12-1450'.

How can I expand the year range of `DateTimePicker` for the Hijri calendar?

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTimePicker.Date.MaxDate = x`?

Comment: @David, yes i tried that.. not working

Comment: you cant see [msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) but see an example of how to create your own on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/570197/asp-net-datepicker-user-control-hijri-gregorian-sh)